# Android List View Item is not working correctly

Tags: android, android-listview

i am trying to show view form listviewitem, when i checked the item from listitems but it does not working. Here is code below which i am using.

```
public class ContentList<View> extends ListActivity {
        String [] list = {"List Item 1","List Item 2","List Item 3"};  


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_list);

        ListView lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,list));
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,int pos, long id){
        CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView) v;
        Toast.makeText(this, list[pos] + "checked : "+ !item.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "it does not working"

Comment: @codeMagic, actually i am tryring textfiltering when i check item from itemlisf.

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't explain what the issue is that you are having

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems and they are both with your `Toast`:

1. Since you are in an `onClick()`, instead of `this` your `Context` should be `ContentList.this`
2. The second `param` of `makeText()` takes either a `CharSequence` or an `int` but you have a `boolean` in there with `isChecked()` so you need to determine what that should be before this line and use "true" or "false" or whatever you want but it needs to be a `CharSequence`

If these don't fix your problem then please state clearly what the exact problem is and if it is crashing then post logcat.